# MLPerf Nvidia benchmarks failure: Command 'cat /sys/module/mlx5_core/version' returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: machine-learning, gpu, benchmarking, nvidia

I am evaluating MLPerf benchmarks and clone the MLPerf repo: github.com/mlperf/training_results_v0.6.git.

Nvidia drivers for Tesla T4 GPU are installed and loaded fine. Docker and nvidia-container-toolkit are also installed and tested. However, whenever I try to run any NVIDIA benchmarks in directory: training_results_v0.6/NVIDIA/benchmarks, it fails with error:
" Command 'cat /sys/module/mlx5_core/version' returned non-zero exit status 1"

Comment: Do you have  Mellanox network adaptors and drivers installed?

Comment: What package to install? It is a AWS Cloud instance with NVidia GPU. Why there is a dependency on this driver? I am using single node configuration of the benchmark.

Comment: Those benchmarks seem like they are for infiniband coupled DGX-1 or DGX-2 nodes. If you don't have that hardware, and it seems you don't, why do you think you can run them?

Answer (score 0):

github.com/mlperf/training_results_v0.7.git is working fine for NVIDIA benchmarks.